# display a modal in a JavaScript function trigger in jVectorMap

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-modal, jvectormap

I am working with jVectorMap and I need to show a modal that will fetch data from database and display the result in a modal.

I want to trigger a modal for the following JavaScript function:

```
onMarkerSelected: function (event, index, isSelected, selectedMarkers) {
          $('#myModal').modal('show');
    }
```

My Modal is:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="largeModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModal" aria-hidden="true">
    // fetch data from db by id
</div>
```

Apparently this doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the HTML of your modal, you are defining it with id "largeModal". So your JS call should be:

> $('#largeModal').modal('show');